# Symfony ManyToOne relation change type

Tags: symfony, orm, entity, dbal

I have 2 entities when 1 is managed by Symfony and other is not

## Entity not managed by Symfony

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="p_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Permission
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Permission", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="permission_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $permission;
}
```

## Entity managed by Symfony

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Permission
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="p_permission")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PermissionRepository")
 */
class Permission
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="permission_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="permission", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $user;
}
```

I need to save `User` entity but `permission` can't be null, when no relation, value is set to 0.

After my research i find that `User::permission` is receiving type of `Permission::id`, but i want that `User::permission` type to be `nullidentity`

### PS: Null\IdentityType

```
namespace App\DBAL\Types\Null;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\IntegerType as DeafaultType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class IdentityType extends DeafaultType
{
    const NULLIDENTITY = 'nullidentity';

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NULLIDENTITY;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        // dd($this);
        return $value === null? 0: (int)$value;
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value === 0? null: (int)$value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In symfony the best practice to validate on a entity is the [Doctrine Event Subscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html).

You can make one subscriber and check, change, delete, insert or run the code you like. You have events than triggers on persist,update or on flush.

For your problem just validate the entities and change as you like.

**Edit**

Add one example as requested.

First you have to register it in the service.yaml

```
App\EventSubscribers\EntitySubscriber:
   tags:
     - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default}
```

And after create a class like this

```
class EntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriber{

public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        Events::prePersist
    ];
}

public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
  /*Continue for other entities or add the user entity in the if statement*/
    if (!$args->getObject() instanceof Permission) {
        return;
    }
     
      /*Do what you need here, use the $args for more options*/

} 
}
```

You can find all event [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)

Comment: have some example to do that? because i do that but dont understand how to achive that.

Comment: `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()`, `@ORM\PrePersist()` and `@ORM\PreUpdate()`

Comment: See my edit and try it outside of entity. There you can insert in construct() all the classes you want and add it in all the entities you like to check. 

Hint: Try to make specific Subscribers for small jobs as they all run at the same time and can be hard to find in debugging.

Comment: its not help me so much, because i can't set $this->permission = 0, its trow error of type

Comment: As I suggested in my comment you need to use the $args variable to take the current entity $entity=$args->getObject(); and then change it $enitity->setPermision(0); or $entity->permission =0; or call another function/class.

Comment: Kosta Kolovos it iposible to asign integet to variable that need class, trow error

Comment: I am sorry, maybe i don't quite understand. I answer how to validate or change the value of a property before you submit it to the database. If is invalid because use annotation to pass only specific entity type , just change it. Or , if i may suggest, enter to your database this default permission and give it as default (if is empty) to your entity like: private $permission = 'value'; . Is database problem not php. If you use a foreign key constraint to a table is because you don't want anything else. How to enter not valid value for this constraint you set not to break in your code?